# How can i find img src value from a Text with asp.net?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, string, substring

I have a html text like that:

```
string htmltext="<p style="text-align: left;" align="center"><img src="../image/1.jpg" alt="" width="310" height="162" /></p>";
```

And i want to find only src value (../image/1.jpg) from this string. 
help me please.

Answer (score 0):

ASPX:

```
<p style="text-align: left;" align="center">
 <img src="../image/1.jpg" alt="1" id="myImage" width="310" 
   height="162" runat="server" />
</p>
```

CODE-BEHIND:

```
string src = myImage.Src;
```

[Making Sense of ASP.NET Paths](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2009/Dec/21/Making-Sense-of-ASPNET-Paths)